# C++ Expressions like cerr, exit, string not recognized in eclipse c++ IDE windows

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse C/C++ IDE and I have the following code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace g2o;
using namespace Eigen;

// sort according to max id, dimension
 struct IncrementalEdgesCompare {
 bool operator()(SparseOptimizer::Edge* const & e1, SparseOptimizer::Edge*  const & e2)
{
const SparseOptimizer::Vertex* to1 = static_cast<const       SparseOptimizer::Vertex*>(e1->vertices()[1]);
const SparseOptimizer::Vertex* to2 = static_cast<const SparseOptimizer::Vertex*>(e2->vertices()[1]);

int i11 = e1->vertices()[0]->id(), i12 = e1->vertices()[1]->id();
if (i11 > i12){
  swap(i11, i12);
}
int i21 = e2->vertices()[0]->id(), i22 = e2->vertices()[1]->id();
if (i21 > i22){
  swap(i21, i22);
}
if (i12 < i22)
  return true;
if (i12 > i22)
  return false;
// push the odometry to be the first
return to1->dimension() > to2->dimension();
  }
 };

 void sigquit_handler(int sig)
 {
 if (sig == SIGINT) {
  hasToStop = 1;
  static int cnt = 0;
  if (cnt++ == 2) {
  cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " forcing exit" << endl;
  exit(1);
 }
 }
 }
```

My problem is that typical c++ expressions as cerr, exit string are not recognized. What is the problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _"are not recognized"_? From intellisense or when you compile your project? In case of the former, it's an indexer problem. In case adjust your actual toolchain and rerun the indexer.

Comment: what do you mean 'rerun the indexer'? build the project?

Comment: Answer my primary question 1st please. Are you familiar with any basic features of Eclipse CDT? I meant **rerun the indexer** not rebuild, it's available from the right mouse click menu in the project view.

Comment: I do not use intellsense. They are not recognized when I import the project, and not after I compiled it. I guess it is an indexing problem. 'Index' tab gives me the following possibilities: Rebuild, Freshen All Files, Update with Modified Files, Re-resolve Unresolved Includes, Search for Unresolved Includes. Which option do you mean? My ToolchainEditor is GNU Autotools Toolchain.

Comment: I tried Cygwin GCC as toolchain, but nothing changes.

Comment: So what's your actual toolchain installed, MinGW?  How's the project built, do you use custom make files?

Comment: No, Cygwin is installed.

Comment: The project is built using CMakeLists.txt files and MakeFiles.

Comment: ^^ Please add such information to your question to improve it, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the indexer, where the standard include files can be found.

Go to your project settings and add the path to the standard include files in the "Paths and Symbols" section as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm).

Rebuild the index afterwards, or choose yes when asked for.

Eclipse CDT cannot retrieve that information if you use CMake as build system for your project, instead of an internal builder.

Comment: But what are the standard include files?

Comment: They are appearing somewhere at `c:\cygwin\usr\include` and down there. Depends on where you've installed cygwin. I have noticed that it works better, if you're running Eclipse CDT from a cygwin shell instead of using the desktop symbol. Especially path resolution from windows `\` vs standard `/` path delimiters causes problems all the way using cygwin. Better portability usually can be achieved using MinGW as for my experiences.

Comment: I included it, but some includes like #include <iostream>
#include <fstream> are still unresolved.

Comment: Track down the c++ specific directories, and add these also.

Comment: They are in the c:\cygwin\usr\include directory, which I included, but it is probably not necessary to add each subdirectory (this would be many). Still they are unresolved (after rebuilding).

Comment: _"... but it is probably not necessary to add each subdirectory (this would be many). ..."_ The indexer is less forgiving about this as you would like to have it to be :-P ..